# Petición múltiple de permisos

Tags: java, android, permisos

Estoy desarrollando una app que registra las llamadas recibidas, y necesito de una serie de permisos. No se el motivo, pero no consigo que me pida los permisos que le pido, no hace nada, se queda en blanco Este es el código:

Y esta es la ruta que sigue usando las marcas del Log.v que he ido colocando:

MainActivityMENSAJE: 3

registrodellamadas.MainActivityMENSAJE: PIDO PERMISOS

registrodellamadas.MainActivityMENSAJE: MULTIPLES

registrodellamadas.MainActivityMENSAJE: permisosMultiples

registrodellamadas.MainActivityMENSAJE: request Multiples

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getName() + "MENSAJE ";
    private static final int READPHONE = 1, READCALL = 2, READCONTACS = 3, ALL = 4;
    private final String[] CONJUNTO_PERMISOS = new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS};
    private List<String> permisosNodados = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        verificarPermisos();
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void verificarPermisos() {
        for (String cad : CONJUNTO_PERMISOS) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (checkSelfPermission(cad) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    permisosNodados.add(cad);
                }
            }
        }
        Log.v(TAG, String.valueOf(permisosNodados.size()));
        pidePermisos();
    }


    private void pidePermisos() {
        Log.v(TAG, "PIDO PERMISOS");
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (!permisosNodados.isEmpty()) {
                if (permisosNodados.size() > 1) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "MULTIPLES");
                    permisosMultiples();
                } else {
                    permisosNodados.size();
                    if (checkSelfPermission(CONJUNTO_PERMISOS[1]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(CONJUNTO_PERMISOS[2]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        Log.v(TAG, "PHONE");
                        permisoPhoneState(); //0
                    } else if (checkSelfPermission(CONJUNTO_PERMISOS[0]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(CONJUNTO_PERMISOS[2]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        Log.v(TAG, "CALL");
                        permisoCollLog();//1
                    } else if (checkSelfPermission(CONJUNTO_PERMISOS[0]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(CONJUNTO_PERMISOS[1]) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        Log.v(TAG, "CONTACT");
                        permisoContact();//2
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            Log.v(TAG, "Tengo todos los permisos");
        }
    }


    private void permisosMultiples() {
        Log.v(TAG, "permisosMultiples");
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(CONJUNTO_PERMISOS[0]) ||
                    shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(CONJUNTO_PERMISOS[1]) ||
                    shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(CONJUNTO_PERMISOS[2])) {

                explicacionDetallada(ALL, CONJUNTO_PERMISOS);
            } else {
                Log.v(TAG, "request Multiples");
                requestPermissions(new String[]{String.valueOf(CONJUNTO_PERMISOS)}, ALL);
            }
        }else{
            Log.v(TAG, "permisosMultiples obtenidos");
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi") //0
    private void permisoPhoneState() {
        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(CONJUNTO_PERMISOS[0])) {
            explicacionDetallada(READPHONE, CONJUNTO_PERMISOS[0]);
        } else {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{CONJUNTO_PERMISOS[0]}, READPHONE);
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")//1
    private void permisoCollLog() {
        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(CONJUNTO_PERMISOS[2])) {
            explicacionDetallada(READCONTACS, CONJUNTO_PERMISOS[2]);
        } else {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{CONJUNTO_PERMISOS[2]}, READCONTACS);
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")//2
    private void permisoContact() {
        if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(CONJUNTO_PERMISOS[2])) {
            explicacionDetallada(READCONTACS, CONJUNTO_PERMISOS[2]);
        } else {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{CONJUNTO_PERMISOS[2]}, READCONTACS);
        }
    }


    private void explicacionDetallada(int codigo_permiso, String... cad) {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.titulo_permiso);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.mensaje_permiso);
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.aceptar, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{String.valueOf(cad)}, codigo_permiso);
                }
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancelar, null);
        builder.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case READPHONE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "Solo tienes READPHONE");
                    faltaPermisos();
                }
                break;
            case READCALL:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "Solo tienes READCALL");
                    faltaPermisos();
                }
            case READCONTACS:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "Solo tienes READCONTACTS");
                    faltaPermisos();
                }
                break;
            case ALL:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.v(TAG, "Los tienes todos");
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void faltaPermisos() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.titulo_permiso_requerido);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.mensaje_permiso_requerido);
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.Salir, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Tienes los permisos en el manifest?

Comment: Si si. Los tres

Comment: Puede ser por como se lee el array? que lo lea tipo [Ljava.lang.String;@4ff8f10?

Comment: Aquí dices?:


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

Comment: Puedes editar la pregunta y agregar ahí para que se visualice mejor.

Comment: Si los tienes definidos en el AndroidManifest.xml verdad?

Comment: Si si, el manifesto los tiene

Comment: No se cual será tu error pero hay una [forma más simple de pedir permisos](https://medium.com/@ajinkya.kolkhede1/requesting-runtime-permissions-using-new-activityresult-api-cb6116551f00) que tal vez quieras probar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu error esta en esta línea:

```
requestPermissions(new String[]{String.valueOf(CONJUNTO_PERMISOS)}, ALL);
```

Debería ser directamente:

```
requestPermissions(CONJUNTO_PERMISOS, ALL);
```

Estas convirtiendo el array de todos los permisos a un *String* y eso agregándolo como un objeto del array.

Y es correcta la sugerencia que te dieron de mirar el post para mejorar la forma en la que estas pidiendo los permisos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu comentario, parece que ahora funciona!. Estoy repasando el enlace que han puesto, se ve mucho más claro.